# Can not access firebase Realtime database in my web app

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am developing firebase webapp and faced one problem.
I cannot access(read/write) firebase realtime database.

```
 <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.12.0/firebase.js"></script>
<script>
var config = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyCPYu_iqHjNoXjMfdMVLoYs5Graf2gdz7I",
    authDomain: "sharing-is-caring-967c8.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://sharing-is-caring-967c8.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "sharing-is-caring-967c8",
    storageBucket: "sharing-is-caring-967c8.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "884406512169"
  };
firebase.initializeApp(config);

    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword("myemail@gmail.com", "Qqqq123").then(function(info) {
        var uid = info.uid;
        firebase.database().ref('users/' + uid + '/userDetails').once('value').then(function(data) {
            alert(data)
        }).catch(function(error) {
            alert(error.message);
        });
    }).catch(function(error) {
        // Handle Errors here.
        var errorCode = error.code;
        var errorMessage = error.message;
        alert(errorMessage);
        // ...
    });
</script>
```

SignInWithEmailAndPassword work fine.
And At database part, 
once('value') function does not response anymore.
There is no success and no fail.
There isn't any error message and always silence

Rules of Realtime Database

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null",
      "threads": {
        "$tid": {
          "messages": {
            ".indexOn": ["read", "date"]
          }
        }
      }
  }
}
```

[Fire base Web Setup Guide Screenshot of my Firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtpAL.png)

Database structure

```
{
  "users" : {
    "BzucCBivhiRUogK5GeNrMV6k6M83" : {
      "userDetails" : {
        "displayName" : "Stanislav Sergeev",
        "email" : "stanislav.atos@yahoo.com",
        "notifications" : true,
        "phoneNumber" : "",
        "profile_image" : "",
        "pushToken" : "ec7iJ7Mt7Lg:APA91bFb8NK2XeaLVUgr-DEPRFuLMDCk9_tIr_eHBjmuZPnHDUvFuCsj3kez4F5-Y9CjVXOY6VlsFi5nlazSZys4KBjwCKcpINbV5S2ZEaH09aWZ6sLga8dOja-UIp3Iz3DSOAb4bcH4"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It seems there is a typo in your indexing rules: $tid instead of $uid

Comment: Just sec, I will attach. And did you face this problem before?

Comment: @Stanislas Sergeev Note that you can easily get a text export (JSON) of your Database by clicking the Export button in your Firebase Database console

Comment: But there are too much data

Comment: @Stanislas Sergeev You may delete most of the data and keep a set of "meaningfull" nodes showing the structure

Comment: Actually, it worked until few days ago. but suddenly it doesn't work

Comment: This project is published and i cannot delete data]

Comment: I mean deleting the data in the export you generate from the console!

Comment: Also, have you double check the rules are still like that on the Firebase Console. Because it may happens that the rules are overwritten during a deployment via the CLI.

Comment: I changed $tid to $uid, but the result is same

Comment: I attached database structure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had same issue before and it is related with your Location.
Please try to use VPN.

Comment: It's related with firebase membership. The free version sometimes doesn't work in some location. I don't know the clear location, but that is.

Answer (score 0):

So, based on the comments and your database structure:

Firstly, I don't understand what the following piece of rule is for?

```
 "threads": {
    "$tid": {
      "messages": {
        ".indexOn": ["read", "date"]
      }
    }
  }
```

Secondly, can you try just with the basic rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

Thirdly, are you sure you are looged in? What do you get if you do

```
var uid = info.uid;
console.log(uid);
```

---

PS: note that the method you are using is apparently going to be deprecated, see 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#signInWithEmailAndPassword

---

EDIT: This is working, I've reproduced your case. Note the `return` and the `data.val()`.

```
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword("azerty@nmw.com", "****")
    .then(function (info) {
        var uid = info.uid;
        console.log(uid);
        return firebase.database().ref('users/' + uid + '/userDetails').once('value');
    })
    .then(function (data) {
        console.log(data.val());
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        alert(error.message);
    });
```

Comment: @StanislavSergeev And what happens if you query with the simple set of rules in place?

Comment: None happen. I changed to rule as simple, but it doesn't work
The important thing is that I have iOS app also and it works even though web app doesn't work

Comment: @StanislavSergeev Try again please. It works perfectly well for me, with the same data structure than you and with simple rules (i.e.     ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null").  Note that in my code the output is done in the browser console, not via an alert.